# citation on page 1 undefined, there are undefined references

Tags: bibliographies

I am new to the Mac latex. I have write a simple sentence and am trying to generate the references but i am getting the error citation on page 1 undefined and there are undefined references. Kindly help me in this regards. I am looking forward to hearing from seniors and expert. Thank you

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

generating references in the draft \cite{rout2016study} 


\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}

\bibliography{Khan.bib}

\end{document}
```

bibgraphy file is

```
@article{rout2016study,
    Author = {Rout, Satya Prakash},
    Date-Added = {2020-10-02 03:20:30 +0500},
    Date-Modified = {2020-10-02 03:22:03 +0500},
    Journal = {Indian Journal of Science and Technology},
    Pages = {20},
    Title = {Study and Emulation of 10G-EPON Access Network},
    Volume = {9},
    Year = {2016}}
```

Comment: you need to run pdflatex then bibtex then pdflatex again

Comment: Does [this procedure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565058/how-to-properly-compile-and-run-biblatex) solve your problem?

Comment: still the problem in. I have run the latex then bibtex and then latex but the problem facing still don't generate the references