# Texstudio Biber compiling error

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber

I'm trying to use biblatex with TexStudio but am running into difficulties.

I tried to set up Texstudio baed on the following instructions: [How to properly compile and run BibLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565058/how-to-properly-compile-and-run-biblatex), but the compiling does not even work on a file that doesn't have a bibliography.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Below is a photo of my Texstudio compiling settings. For the default compiler I have: pdflatex, biber, pdflatex, pdflatex for the default compiler and made biber the default bibliography tool

[image: Photo of my Texstudio settings]

I am on Texstudio 4.7.1, on the newest version 4.7.2 I had some weird highlighting of text while typing in equations, so I went back to 4.7.1.

I got the following error when I ran the above tex file with the above settings:

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test_file".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber "test_file"

dyld[42643]: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib Referenced from: <13F64F77-06B2-3380-939A-92FD929CDF70> /private/var/folders/zz/py2wclgx0w16rzwlr4mz3f340000gn/T/par-6d61787a686f75/cache-6bef3f811cde577dd70e44f9f5046ebc66712c46/biber Reason: tried: '/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Error: Command crashed: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber "test_file"

Process exited with error(s)


Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test_file".tex

Process exited normally


Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test_file".tex

Process exited normally
```

Evidently something is going wrong in the Biber step, but how do I fix it? If I just change the default compiler to just do pdflatex, everything works fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0):

[This is here because it is too long for a comment and the OP has too little rep for chat. It is not an answer and will get deleted or rewritten later, so please ignore.]

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test_file".tex

Process exited normally
```

pdfTeX compiles the document fine.

```
Process started: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber "test_file"

dyld[42643]: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib Referenced from: <13F64F77-06B2-3380-939A-92FD929CDF70> /private/var/folders/zz/py2wclgx0w16rzwlr4mz3f340000gn/T/par-6d61787a686f75/cache-6bef3f811cde577dd70e44f9f5046ebc66712c46/biber Reason: tried: '/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/local/lib/perl5/5.20/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libperl.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
Error: Command crashed: /Library/TeX/texbin/biber "test_file"

Process exited with error(s)
```

Even though you don't have a bibliography, you've asked to run Biber. Biber expects to find a file generated by the pdfTeX run. Trying to run Biber when that file doesn't exist will give an error. So an error is expected here.

That said, I'm not sure *this* error is expected. It looks as if `biber` may be crashing before even looking for the generated file. For example, if I compile your code, I get

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'prawf.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'prawf.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

where the log file says

```
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - This is Biber 2.19
[0] Config.pm:310> INFO - Logfile is 'prawf.blg'
[90] biber:340> INFO - === Mer Chw 21, 2024, 04:21:06
[280] Utils.pm:410> ERROR - Cannot find 'prawf.bcf'!
[280] Biber.pm:136> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

Do you have a file `<filename>.blg`?

What do `which -a perl` and `perl --version` return?

How did you install TeX? (E.g. MacTeX? Or ...?)

Comment: Sorry, I think I've posted here maybe only once or twice before.

Ok, I looked into this issue more, I have Tex Live on a Mac (so I guess MacTex?). I opened the Tex Live that I have on my Mac now, and when I opened it, it told me to upgrade and that it couldn't connect to something because my version is so out of date. I looked at the Tex Live that my Texstudio is using, and I have the 2014 and 2015 versions, so very out of date. Further, I looked more into the Biber package and saw that you can check if you even have Biber installed if you type "biber --help" in terminal...

Comment: And I did that and got a very similar error (too long to post here). So I'm guessing right now for some reason the Tex Live I have doesn't have a working Biber package (at least one that works with the Texstudio version I have). I'm currently downloading the newest version of Mac Tex, but it's taking a long time for some reason. Once I get that downloaded, I'll see if it has a working Biber package and go from there.

Comment: @MaxZhou That sounds like the best thing to do, so fingers crossed. I asked what you installed because there are other ways to install TeX Live on a Mac. (The error message told me you were almost certainly using a Mac.) MacTeX is the most straightforward, though. My guess is you have a mismatch somewhere e.g. a `perl` which is too new for your `biber`. `perl` is presumably your system `perl` unless you've installed another explicitly, so I'm guessing your OS X is rather newer than your TeX Live install.

Comment: I got it to work! After installing the newest version of MacTex, there were hundreds of packages to update. After that was all done, everything magically works. I've entered the bibliography entries, but now I'm having issues with the style file. I made a new post, I would greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710163/texstudio-biblatex-cant-find-custom-bibliography-style-file