# TeXStudio Biblatex can't find custom bibliography style file

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, texstudio, bibliographystyle

I'm using TexStudio 4.7.1 and BibLatex 3.19 and trying to use a custom style file. I have the following tex file in the same folder as the uclathes.sty file:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=uclathes]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{thesisbib.bib}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\parencite{II_1book}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

When I compile using TexStudio, I get the following errors

```
Package biblatex Error: Style 'uclathes' not found. \RequireBibliographyStyle{\blx@bbxfile}
Package biblatex Error: Style 'uclathes' not found. \RequireCitationStyle{\blx@cbxfile}
Package biblatex Error: Command '\cite' undefined. \parencite
Missing $ inserted. \parencite{II_
Extra }, or forgotten $. \parencite{II_1book}
Missing $ inserted.
Missing \endgroup inserted.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Undefined control sequence.
Missing } inserted.
Extra \endgroup.
'\parencite' not defined by citation style.
Empty bibliography
There were undefined references.
Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) test_file(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

Everything works fine if I omit the `style=uclathes`. I have tried using `style=uclathes.bib` also, to no avail.

There is also a custom document class I am using, uclathes.cls, and if I put that in the same folder as a test file with that documentclass, everything goes okay. Is this something special with .sty files for biblatex or is something deeper wrong with my LaTeX setup?

I tried putting the tex file the style files (for the documentclass and bibliography style) in its own folder, and it still doesn't work. I tried using both the uclathes documentclass and the uclathes bibliography style together, but again it doesn't work. There are several associated .clo files and Texstudio can find all of them, except for the .bst file.

Comment: If you have a `.bst` file, you need to use BibTeX rather than Biblatex/Biber. Is Biblatex supposed to work with this style? Where did you get `uclathes`?

Comment: Hi, thanks, I eventually googled around and found this out too...I had to switch all my parencites to cites, which was annoying as some of them had pre/post words, but now it's fixed. Now everything seems to be working.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was solved in comments and concerns a custom style not generally available.

Comment: Sure, that's fine with me. Is that something I do on my end?

Comment: Nah. That's an automatic message. Whoever is around just votes until there's enough or a moderator notices and finishes. You don't need to do anything ;).